# django body background image not loading

Tags: python, django, static, background-image

urls.py:

```
url(r'^index/', index),
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')
```

base.html:  (in the `templates` directory)

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<body style="background-image: url({% static "/static/arch.png" %})">
</body>
```

And the `arch.png` is in the static folder in the app directory `info/static/arch.png` .

The result is a white screen page.

Comment: You are also missing `'` after `(` and before `)`

Comment: @gtlambert , those are entirely optional

Comment: oh really? I never realised...

Comment: @gtlambert , yep! Here's the info [in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri). Quotes and white space are entirely optional.

Comment: @mevius Great - I obviously need to improve my CSS!

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because the path in the `static` tag should be *relative* to the static directory. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static):

> Uses the configured `STATICFILES_STORAGE` storage to create the full URL for the given **relative path**

You're using an absolute path. Instead, you should use:

```
{% static "arch.png" %}
```

Note the omission of the leading forward slash, as well as the name of the `static` directory. If you're still experiencing issues, make sure your dirs are set up properly in *settings.py*.

Comment: @mevius, `{% static "arch.png" %}` does not working again.

Comment: Then as mentioned, you have some other issue. You need to turn on debugging to determine what the actual issue is.

Comment: @mevius, do you mean this `DEBUG = True` in the setting.py file?

Comment: What is STATICFILES_STORAGE exactly? I have read the link you noticed but didn't understand what to do exactly well. Can guide me more clear please?